# Python does not see env variables set from Jenkins Parameterized build

Tags: python, python-2.7, jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to retrieve the parameters set from the jenkins build into my python script, but am having trouble. I understand the parameters set from here:
[image]

Are set as env variables and all I have to do in python is do:

```
# Env variables
UPDATE_DATA = os.environ.get('update_data')
ALL_BUILDS = os.environ.get('all_builds')
```

However I am getting None for those values. When I do an echo of those parameters in my jenkins script before my python script runs, I could see them being printed out correctly. However, for some reason python does not see them. If I go manually into a terminal and export a variable and run my python script, it works.. So I'm completely lost here.

Jenkins server is running on linux. Using python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like when I ran the python script in the Jenkins config (not inside a file within my project) like how @souravatta suggested, it found the env variable. So that means the env variable Jenkins is setting, is on a different instance somehow (even though they are on the same computer, same user). I just did a workaround where I wrote the env variables to a file and then just read that file in my python script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the boolean variable like this:

[image]

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply @souravatta. I actually have a python script outside my configuration which I am running. But anyways, I tried putting this in my python script and it does not work.

Comment: Actually when I do exactly what your doing, they always print True no matter if it is set to false or true.